# How do I configure Haproxy and Apache when adding SSL?

Tags: apache, https, openssl, haproxy

Currently I am using Haproxy to route my application which has a websocket back end and an Apache back end.

I have configured Apache's virtual host to use SSL. Now I'm confused like do I have to configure Haproxy to use SSL connection and send encrypted data to SSL enabled Apache or terminate SSL at Haproxy and send unencrypted data to Apache (do I have to disable the SSL on Apache in this case?)

Comment: Haproxy is the only public-facing server, correct? If yes, that's what you must configure to use SSL. Try [Mozilla's configuration generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) for examples. Best practice is to also protect the connection between your Haproxy server and any backends, especially if these exist on different machines. You can use SSL for that too, but in that situation you can use self-signed certificates since those connections are not public-facing.

Comment: You say your site has both a web socket back end and an Apache back end.   What is the front end?

Comment: Mobile Apps on Android and iOS